# Retrieve MetaMask version in web3.js

Tags: web3js, metamask

Is there a way to determine the version of the currently installed MetaMask extension from web3.js?

I can't find it by inspecting the Web3 instance.

Comment: Hi there. Do you specifically want the Metamask version, or rather the version of web3 it's injecting?

Comment: Of MetaMask. To see if it supports some recently implemented functionality.